# how can I get the color of the background in WPF

Tags: wpf, background

In my small WPF program I want to show the name of the "background color" of the client area on a mouse click in am message box .... How can I do it?

System : Win7(32-bit)/VS2008

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You need to get the `Background` object of the element you want to get the color for.  Do this in your mouse click event like this:

NOTE: You must check for which brush type, basically `SolidColorBrush` would only really apply as a gradient would not be a simple color.

EXAMPLE:

```cs
Brush backgroundColor = LayoutRoot.Background;

if (backgroundColor is SolidColorBrush)
{
    string colorValue = ((SolidColorBrush)backgroundColor).Color.ToString();
}
```